# Changing the css color every second

Tags: jquery, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to loop a css background image with Jquery every few seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374867/how-to-loop-a-css-background-image-with-jquery-every-few-seconds)

I'm wondering how to achieve a simple "animation" effect of colors changing every second and if there is a way to animate the animation it can be even better.

I have just tried something like:

```
$('.box').delay(1000).css("background","red");
```

And it doesn't work at all (the delay function isn't working).. anyways i need like two of them:

```
$('.box').delay(1000).css("background","red");
$('.box').delay(1000).css("background","green");
```

So that it becomes red -> wait a second and becomes green -> becomes red again..

Is it possible? thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374867/how-to-loop-a-css-background-image-with-jquery-every-few-seconds <— perhaps this question can help?

Comment: jquery.animate can do colors: http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/

Comment: @jblasco wish i could give you a +1 for that :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $('body').animate( { backgroundColor: 'red' }, 300)
            .animate( { backgroundColor: 'green' }, 300);
    }, 1000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/theSifter/yR6jc/

Answer (score 3):

```
setInterval(function() {
    var box = $('.box');
    if (box.css('background-color') == 'red') {
        box.css({'background-color':'green'});
    }
    else {
        box.css({'background-color':'red'});
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Is there any way to loop the color changing? Now it works but it changes once and that's it.

Comment: You could loop, but there is no way to tell the javascript engine to relax and update the user display without setTimeout or setInterval. A loop without setTimeout or setInterval will just crash the browser (eventually).

Answer (score 2):

```
<h1 id="ho">Ho ho ho!</h1>
<h2 id="mc">Merry Christmas!</h2>

<script>
    var flag = false;
    setInterval(function() {
        flag = !flag;
        $("#ho").css("background", flag ? "red" : "green");
        $("#mc").css("background", flag ? "green" : "red");
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use the javascript setInterval method :

See here:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

so:

```
setInterval(function() {
// Code to execute every second
}, 1000);
```

Comment: http://w3fools.com maybe?? ;)

Comment: Maybe somethings could be wrong there, but the example i saw wasn't..