# Background image rotation in a loop

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have daveloped with an image in background as follows:

```
body {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: url('/images/bg.jpg') top center no-repeat;
  background-attachment: scroll;
}
```

Image is 2000px width.
I would like to rotate image background with three images `bg1.jpg`,  `bg2.jpg` and `bg3.jpg`.    Could you help me with finding easy solution to do it?

Comment: How do you want to rotate the image? Based on an interval or interaction? With or without a transition effect? Etc..

Comment: See this question ----->  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374867/how-to-loop-a-css-background-image-with-jquery-every-few-seconds

Comment: What have you tried?  Please show us the code you have so far, and tell us exactly which part you're stuck on.

Answer (score 2):

Since you've posted this with jQuery, I'll assume a jQuery solution would be preferable.

How about this example using a jQuery plug-in: http://www.magneticwebworks.com/jquery-rotating-page-background/

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off by creating 3 divs that are positioned at 0, 0 and stretch the whole page. Put a background image in each of these divs.

```
<div id="bg1"></div>
<div id="bg2" style="display: none"></div>
<div id="bg3" style="display: none"></div>
```

Then you can use jQuery animation (or basically any image slider plugin) to change the background.